# Student in Germany with a Schengen visa

Tags: pakistani-citizens, schengen-visas

I am a Pakistani student in Germany with a Schengen visa. I need to visit the UK. What would be the (short stay) visa requirements?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa This might help you. Fill in steps and you'll see if you need a visa and which one.

Comment: You can't use your Schengen visa to enter the UK. Without your nationality we can't help you further.

Answer (score 4):

Your Schengen visa isn't valid for the UK although it might make it more likely that you'll be granted a UK visa.

You can check the [UK government web site](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) to determine what visa you might require, if any.

In your case, as a Pakistani citizen you will probably need a 
[Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa): the web site  I linked to will tell exactly what you need if your needs differ.

You can apply for a visa through [TLSContact](https://uk.tlscontact.com/de/DUS/splash.php), who have centres in Munich, Dusseldorf and Berlin.

Comment: There are some purposes for which a visitor needs a different kind of visa, but the question does not specify the purpose of the visit.

Comment: @phoog Good point. Answer updated accordingly